# Error converting FaceNet model into ONNX format

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx, facenet

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution: Linux Ubuntu 19.10
- Tensorflow Version: 1.15
- Python version: 3.7

**Issue**

I downloaded a tensorflow model of FaceNet from this [page](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet), and I'm trying to convert it from .pb into a .onnx file, however it raises the following error:

**To Reproduce**

```
root@xesk-VirtualBox:/home/xesk/Desktop# python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model home/xesk/Desktop/2s/20180402-114759/20180402-114759.pb --output model.onnx

    2020-08-03 20:18:05.081538: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    2020-08-03 20:18:05.081680: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
    2020-08-03 20:18:07,431 - WARNING - '--tag' not specified for saved_model. Using --tag serve
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tf2onnx/convert.py", line 171, in
    main()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tf2onnx/convert.py", line 131, in main
    graph_def, inputs, outputs = tf_loader.from_saved_model(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tf2onnx/tf_loader.py", line 288, in from_saved_model
    _from_saved_model_v2(model_path, input_names, output_names, tag, signatures, concrete_function)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tf2onnx/tf_loader.py", line 247, in _from_saved_model_v2
    imported = tf.saved_model.load(model_path, tags=tag) # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 603, in load
    return load_internal(export_dir, tags, options)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 614, in load_internal
    loader_impl.parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 56, in parse_saved_model_with_debug_info
    saved_model = _parse_saved_model(export_dir)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 110, in parse_saved_model
    raise IOError("SavedModel file does not exist at: %s/{%s|%s}" %
    OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: home/xesk/Desktop/2s/20180402-114759/20180402-114759.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

**Additional context**

I'm not running any CUDA or similars, only CPU.
The model downloaded is the [20180402-114759](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet).
It's the first time I'm working with this tools, and I'm a bit of a beginner in this AI world, so I might be missing something obvious.
Of course, I checked the path and the command syntax several times.
Might be something to do with the format of the files i downloaded?

**EDIT**

Following *Venkatesh Wadawadagi*'s answer, I'm going for Option 1.
Changing the name of the *.meta* file solved the problem of the script from not recognising it.

The script is running more or less correctly, and finishes creating the export_dir directory, with **export_dir > 0 > variables** subfolders. However, they are empty.

The console output is this:

```
xesk@xesk:~/Desktop/UP2S/ACROMEGALLY/20180402-114759$ python3 ./pb2sm
2020-08-10 16:02:26.128846: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-08-10 16:02:26.129114: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-08-10 16:02:26.129137: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (xesk): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-08-10 16:02:26.129501: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-08-10 16:02:26.139076: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2592000000 Hz
2020-08-10 16:02:26.139506: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x44018d0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-10 16:02:26.139520: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py:391: QueueRunner.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.
2020-08-10 16:02:32.681265: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:81] Allocation of 17676288 exceeds 10% of system memory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/beta/Adam
     [[{{node save/SaveV2_1}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pb2sm", line 17, in <module>
    strip_default_attrs=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py", line 595, in add_meta_graph_and_variables
    saver.save(sess, variables_path, write_meta_graph=False, write_state=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 1193, in save
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 1176, in save
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: checkpoint_file})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1180, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1359, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/beta/Adam
     [[node save/SaveV2_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]

Original stack trace for 'save/SaveV2_1':
  File "./pb2sm", line 17, in <module>
    strip_default_attrs=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py", line 589, in add_meta_graph_and_variables
    saver = self._maybe_create_saver(saver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py", line 227, in _maybe_create_saver
    allow_empty=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 828, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 840, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 878, in _build
    build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 499, in _build_internal
    save_tensor = self._AddShardedSaveOps(filename_tensor, per_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 291, in _AddShardedSaveOps
    return self._AddShardedSaveOpsForV2(filename_tensor, per_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 265, in _AddShardedSaveOpsForV2
    sharded_saves.append(self._AddSaveOps(sharded_filename, saveables))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 206, in _AddSaveOps
    save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, saveables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 122, in save_op
    tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1946, in save_v2
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Is it possible that I'm missing some library to install?
Seems to have something to do with some CUDA implementation, which I have none.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

**The command you're using:**

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model home/xesk/Desktop/2s/20180402-114759/20180402-114759.pb --output model.onnx
```

Note that [Facenet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EXPBSXwTaqrSC0OhUdXNmKSh9qJUQ55-/view) trained model that you're using has got only frozen graph (`.pb` file) and checkpoint (`.ckpt`) and does not have **`saved-model`** that your command is looking for.

So basically you are passing the path to the `.pb` file of the frozen graph, which is different from the `.pb` file of a **SavedModel** (which you don't have). Savedmodel will have **`variables`** folder along with `saved_model.pb` file.

That's why the error:

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist
```

Read more about SavedModel [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model).

**To proceed with ONNX conversion, you have two options:**

1. Convert checkpoint to SavedModel:

Use the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56766639/how-to-convert-ckpt-to-pb) for that:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

trained_checkpoint_prefix = 'model-20180402-114759.ckpt-275'
export_dir = os.path.join('export_dir', '0')

graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    # Restore from checkpoint
    loader = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(trained_checkpoint_prefix + '.meta')
    loader.restore(sess, trained_checkpoint_prefix)

    # Export checkpoint to SavedModel
    builder = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                         [tf.saved_model.TRAINING, tf.saved_model.SERVING],
                                         strip_default_attrs=True)
    builder.save()
```

**Note:** `.data`, `.index` and `.meta` should have same prefix then this code will work. So rename `.meta` file.

```
mv model-20180402-114759.meta model-20180402-114759.ckpt-275.meta
```

For example:
[image]

2. Make use of `ckpt` file or `frozen-graph.pb` for onnx conversion

**From checkpoint format:**

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --checkpoint tensorflow-model-meta-file-path --output model.onnx --inputs input0:0,input1:0 --outputs output0:0
```

**From graphdef/frozen-graph format:**

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --graphdef tensorflow-model-graphdef-file --output model.onnx --inputs input0:0,input1:0 --outputs output0:0
```

If your TensorFlow model is in a format other than **`saved model`**, then you need to provide the **`inputs`** and **`outputs`** of the model graph.

From [this](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx):

> If your model is in **checkpoint** or **graphdef** format and you do not know
> the input and output nodes of the model, you can use the
> **summarize_graph** TensorFlow utility. The [**summarize_graph**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms) tool does
> need to be downloaded and built from source. If you have the option of
> going to your model provider and obtaining the model in saved model
> format, then we recommend doing so.

Comment: I tried to go with option2 before, but I could not find the --inputs and --outputs of the model. 
For option1 i created a new environment with python3.7 and tensorflow1.15, as these are the requirements for tf2onnx to work. With that setting, I get this error:
`... in loader.restore(sess, trained_checkpoint_prefix) ...
ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: model-20180402-114759`

Comment: Tried to add the .meta extension to the _trained_checkpoint_prefix_ 
It seems to work a little more, but at the end still gives an error:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file ./model-20180402-114759.meta: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
  [[node save/RestoreV2_356 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]`

Comment: Im running the script in the same folder, where I have the .pb and .meta files

Comment: @Xesk I've edited Option-1 to address your query. **Notice the changes in `code (trained_checkpoint_prefix)` and also read `Note` section**. I suggest you to try option-1 only and ensure that you don't get `not a valid file` or `missing file` etc. errors otherwise it's always prefix and path related issue. Like I mentioned in my answer, to try option-2 you need to know inputs and outputs for which you need to use **`summarize_graph`**.

Comment: thank you for your time and patience. I have edited the question with your update, and the outputs of running it as you are saying. It looks like a big advancement, but still I'm getting some errors... Maybe due to some missing library?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similiar error. In my case, I made a mistake by giving pb file instead of **path/to/savedmodel** which should be the path to the directory containing **saved_model.pb**. So assuming your `20180402-114759.pb` is at directory `home/xesk/Desktop/2s/20180402-114759`, the command should be:

`python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model home/xesk/Desktop/2s/20180402-114759 --output model.onnx`

Please refer to [Getting Started Converting TensorFlow to ONNX](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/tutorials/tf-get-started.html) and [Using the SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) for more information.